# Am doing addcart functionality in mvc4?If i remove the single item in the cart it is not removing anything?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Am doing addcart functionality in mvc4?If i remove the single item in the cart it is not removing anything?

My controller action is.......

```
ManageDatabase _db = new ManageDatabase();

List<Product> cartList = new List<Product>();

 public ActionResult Deletecart(int id)
    {
        var prod = _db.product.Find(id);

        int CartLen = 0;
        cartList.Remove(prod);

        cartList = (List<Product>)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["cartList"]; 


        CartLen = cartList.Count;


        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["CartLen"] = CartLen;

        return RedirectToAction("Details", "Home");



    }
```

Comment: When you debug, what does `cartList.Remove(prod);` return?  How about `cartList`?  Also, it does not appear you are calling `_db.SaveChanges()` anywhere.

Comment: now i edited see the code again

Comment: You initialize `cartList` as a new (empty) list. Then you remove `prod` from it which makes no sense.

Comment: Looks like you believe that the variables at controller level are preserved between calls?

Comment: Still i didnt get output...can u plz guide me by code?

Answer (score 0):

As you've requested to be guided by code, please do the following:

```
ManageDatabase _db = new ManageDatabase();

List<Product> cartList = new List<Product>();

public ActionResult Deletecart(int id) // tell me the value of id
{
    // put breakpoint on next line and click DEBUG
    var prod = _db.product.Find(id); // tell me the value of prod

    int CartLen = 0;
    cartList.Remove(prod); 

    // tell me the value of cartList
    cartList = (List<Product>)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["cartList"]; 

    CartLen = cartList.Count;

    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["CartLen"] = CartLen;

    return RedirectToAction("Details", "Home");
}
```

Once we know what your variables are, we can tell you what's wrong.